# What methods are available on unix for pub sub IPC?

Tags: sockets, unix, publish-subscribe

There are various options for IPC.

Over a network:

- for client-server, can use TCP
- for pub sub, can use UDP multicast

Locally:

- for client-server, can use unix domain sockets
- for pub sub, can use ???

I suppose what I'd be interested in is some kind of file descriptor that supports many readers (subscribers) and many writers (publishers) simultaneously. Is this usage pattern feasible/efficient on unix?

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) and [tcp(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) and [udp(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udp.7.html). Consider [D-bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus)

Comment: The only UNIX way of doing proper PUB/SUB with multiple both readers and writers that does not require extra libraries or a lot of user code needed to implement it yourself one way or another is UDP multicast to a local address. No other way I know of will force the kernel to create a buffer for each reader and to put a copy of each message to each of the buffers automatically. And although it works on Linux it feels like quite a dirty hack and I am not sure it even counts as a proper UNIX-way solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much googling I haven't found a whole lot in the way of ipc multicast, so I have decided to write a program pubsub that takes as arguments a publisher address and a subscriber address, listens and accepts connections on these 2 addresses, and then for each payload received on a publisher connection write it to each of the subscriber connections. It wouldn't surprise me if this is inefficient or reinventing the wheel but I have not come across a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for solutions to a similar problem and found /dev/fanout. Fanout is a kernel module that replicates its input out to all processes reading from it. You can think of it as IPC Broadcast mechanism. Works well for small data payloads according to the author. Multiple processes can write to the device and multiple processes can read from it. I am not sure of atomicity of writes though. Small writes from multiple processes should occur atomically as with FIFOs, etc.

More about Fanout:

http://compgroups.net/comp.linux.development.system/-dev-fanout-a-one-to-many-multi/2869739 
http://www.linuxtoys.org/fanout/fanout.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include more details about the said solution. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

There are Posix message queues too. As `man mq_overview` puts it:

> POSIX  message queues allow processes to exchange data in the form of messages.  This API is distinct from that provided by
>   System V message queues (msgget(2), msgsnd(2), msgrcv(2), etc.), but provides similar functionality.
>
> Message queues are created and opened using mq_open(3); this function returns a message queue descriptor (mqd_t), which  is
>   used  to refer to the open message queue in later calls.  Each message queue is identified by a name of the form /somename;
>   that is, a null-terminated string of up to NAME_MAX (i.e., 255) characters consisting of an initial slash, followed by  one
>   or  more  characters,  none  of which are slashes.  Two processes can operate on the same queue by passing the same name to
>   mq_open(3).
>
> Messages are transferred to and from a queue using mq_send(3) and mq_receive(3).  When a process  has  finished  using  the queue,  it  closes  it  using  mq_close(3), and when the queue is no longer required, it can be deleted using mq_unlink(3).
>   Queue attributes can be retrieved and (in some cases) modified  using  mq_getattr(3)  and  mq_setattr(3).   A  process  can request asynchronous notification of the arrival of a message on a previously empty queue using mq_notify(3).
>
> A  message  queue  descriptor is a reference to an open message queue description (cf.  open(2)).  After a fork(2), a child inherits copies of its parent's message queue descriptors, and these descriptors refer  to  the  same  open  message  queue descriptions  as  the  corresponding  descriptors  in the parent.  Corresponding descriptors in the two processes share the flags (mq_flags) that are associated with the open message queue description.
>
> Each message has an associated priority, and messages are always delivered to the receiving process highest priority first.
>   Message  priorities  range from 0 (low) to sysconf(_SC_MQ_PRIO_MAX) - 1 (high).  On Linux, sysconf(_SC_MQ_PRIO_MAX) returns 32768, but POSIX.1 requires only that an implementation support at least priorities in the range 0 to 31; some  implementations provide only this range.

A more friendly introduction by Michael Kerrisk is available here: http://man7.org/conf/lca2013/IPC_Overview-LCA-2013-printable.pdf

Comment: Just a note, the OP was asking for pub/sub which to my knowledge is not supported by regular POSIX message queues.

Comment: POSIX message queues provide a complete opposite of a pub/sub model! Multiple processes can write messages to a queue even at the same time, but if there is one message in the queue and multiple processes try to read it then only one process will get the message. The same actually goes for both UNIX and INET sockets, there is no universal pub/sub UNIX way! You can implement it using shared memory or memory mapped files or a bunch of UNIX sockets, but I would not bother. If you know that there will only ever be one source and multiple receivers then use shmem/mmap-file. Otherwise just use DBus.